# I need help here my script does not work and there is nothing in the output

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

```
`script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(Player)
    Player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Power").Value -= script.Parent:GetAttribute("Damage")
end)`
```

I expected the damage of the model to romove the player's power

Comment: Well, does the event even trigger?

Comment: @luke100000 No it does not

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help you. Does your model have a ClickDetector named "ClickDetector" in it? Is this a Script or a LocalScript? Where is this located?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
local Part = script.Parent
local ClickD = Part:WaitForChild("ClickDetector")

local function onClick(Player)

    local leaderstats = Player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    if leaderstats then
        
        local Power = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Power")
        local Damage = Part:GetAttribute("Damage")
        if Power and Damage then
            Power.Value -= Damage
        end
    end
end

ClickD.MouseClick:Connect(onClick)
```

It can be a very bad habit to use WaitForChild() for instances that would already be loaded. Replace them with FindFirstChild() will prevent errors from occuring if said instance were to, for some reason, not exist by returning nil.
Another tip would be to use [Event Handlers](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/luau/functions#event-handlers) over [Anonymous Functions](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/luau/functions#anonymous-functions) as Event Handlers can be called again later in the script if needed.